# GPRMC string is not showing after extracting the data - C

Tags: c, string, gps

Im working around PIC with GPS module. My GPS modules send NMEA data

```
$GPRMC,000036.799,V,,,,,0.00,0.00,060180,,,N*40
$GPVTG,0.00,T,,M,0.00,N,0.00,K,N*32
$GPGGA,000036.799,,,,,0,0,,,M,,M,,*4A
$GPGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*1E
$GPGSV,1,1,00*79
$GPGLL,,,,,000036.799,V,N*78
$GPTXT,01,01,02,ANTSTATUS=OPEN*2B
```

Here my intention is to extract "GPRMC" data string from the above. I think i've sucessfully took it off the "GPRMC", but the problem is the exracted data string doesnt have **GPRMC** string. here is the screenshot of my hyperterminal window

[image]

Here is my code:

```c
while (1)
{
    //memset(gpsdata,0,sizeof(gpsdata));
    char c = uartrec2();
    if (c == '$')
    {
        char c1 = uartrec2();
        if (c1 == 'G')
        {
            char c2 = uartrec2();
            if (c2 == 'P')
            {
                char c3 = uartrec2();
                if (c3 == 'R')
                {
                    char c4 = uartrec2();
                    if (c4 == 'M')
                    {
                        char c5 = uartrec2();
                        if (c5 == 'C')
                        {
                            for (i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++)
                            {
                                gpsdata[i] = uartrec2();
                                /* while (gpsdata[i] == '\r' || gpsdata[i] == '\n')
                                {
                                    break;
                                } */
                                if (gpsdata[i] == '\r' ) // Checking for '\r'
                                {
                                    gpsdata[i] = '\0';
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("Bad GPS data");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    uart_str(gpsdata);
    uart_str("\r\n");
}
```

Comment: You really need to improve your coding style. It's critical in your case. I have seen really bad style and yours.

Comment: Hi @iharob. Thanks for the reply. Actually im newbie to C and i will try to change my coding style. Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about just adding it since you know there was it?

```
if (c5 == 'C')
{
    gpsdata[0] = '$';
    gpsdata[1] = 'G';
    gpsdata[2] = 'P';
    gpsdata[3] = 'R';
    gpsdata[4] = 'M';
    gpsdata[5] = 'C';
    for (i = 6 ; i < 100 ; i++)
    {
        gpsdata[i] = uartrec2();
        /* while (gpsdata[i] == '\r' || gpsdata[i] == '\n')
        {
            break;
        } */
        if (gpsdata[i] == '\r' ) // Checking for '\r'
        {
            gpsdata[i] = '\0';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you should do is try to figure out a better way to write this program, this could be

```
int done;
done = 0;
while (done == 0)
{
    const char *string;
    int valid;

    valid = 1;    
    string = "$GPRMC";
    while ((*string != '\0') && ((valid = (uartec2() == *string)) != 0)) 
        string++;    
    if (valid != 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; ++i)
        {
            gpsdata[i] = uartec2();
            if (gpsdata[i] != '\r')
                continue;
            gpsdata[i] = '\0';
        }
        uart_str(gpsdata);
        uart_str("\r\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this will work because `valid` have to be zero to break from the `while` loop. Try this instead of the `while` loop: `while (((valid = (uartec2() == *string++)) != 0) && *string != '\0');`

Comment: The new code `while (((valid = (uartec2() == *string)) != 0) && (*string != '\0')) string++; ` won't work, either since it compare the character next to `$GPRMC` (it should be `,`) with `'\0'` and it makes `valid` zero.

Comment: @MikeCAT Thank you, I am really tired and my brain is going really slow now.

Comment: Hi @iharob i have doubts in while loop `while ((*string != '\0') && ((valid = (uartec2() == *string)) != 0)) `. uartec2() receives char, how i can compare with string "$GPRMC"?  Also if condition is not satisfying `if (valid != 0)`. Thanks..

Comment: You can capture all the characters and store them into an array. What I understand from the original code is that you want to check whether `"$GPRMC"` is found in the file. If you try to understand my code you will see that for instance `*string != '\0'` should be `*string != ','`, if `valid == 0` it means `"$GPRMC"` was not the string that you read.

Comment: Hi @iharob. Thanks for the reply. I've to go through your code. Thanks sir. Learned some useful things...